# Java JLayeredPane Overrides Cursor

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jlayeredpane

I have a multi-layered java application that has a range of JLabel buttons that require the hand cursor such as:

```
button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

However, I have a layer above that has bounds covering the entire application (for drawing pop-ups and such).  Now that I have added the layer above, my cursor doesn't change anymore.  I have tried setting the cursor to null for the layer above, but it has no affect.

Here is the basic layout of the layers:

```
private void create() {
    this.addWindowListener(windowAdapter);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    layers = new JLayeredPane();
    layers.setPreferredSize(this.getSize());

    dashboard = new DashBoard.DashBoardLayer();
    dashboard.setBounds(0, this.getHeight()-275, this.getWidth(),275);

    application = new App.ApplicationLayer();
    application.setBounds(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight()-145);

    filter = new FilterLayer();
    filter.setBounds(0,195,this.getWidth(),490);

    menuBG = MenuLayerBg.getInstance();
    menuBG.setBounds(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

    menuPanes = MenuLayer.getInstance();
    menuPanes.setBounds(0,0,this.getWidth(),this.getHeight());

    layers.add(application, new Integer(0));
    layers.add(filter, new Integer(1));
    layers.add(dashboard, new Integer(2));
    layers.add(menuBG, new Integer(3));
    layers.add(menuPanes, new Integer(4));

    this.add(layers, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MouseEvent is only dispatched to the component on the top. So if your top layers completely cover the components on the bottom layers, they will not receive the MouseEvent.

Take a look at the `LayeredPaneDemo.java` code found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). I made the following change to the code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) {
        JLabel label = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[i],
                                          layerColors[i], origin);
        layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
        origin.x += offset;
        origin.y += offset;

  label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR)); // added
    }
```

Each component is of a fixed smaller size than the entire frame so events will be accepted by components below the top components.

When you run the code the cursor will change on the top two labels.

If you change "Dukes Layer and Position" to be "Yellow" and uncheck the check box, then the cursor will change for all labels.

> However, I have a layer above that has bounds covering the entire application

One possible solution is to "redispatch the mouse events" to the components below the top layer. For an example of this approach check out the `GlassPaneDemo.java` from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Or for a completely different approach you can try overriding the `contains(...)` method of your components to always return false. This way the mouse event will never be dispatched to your component since the mouse point does not belong to the component. I have never tried this before so I don't know if this will cause other problems.

I tried this in the LayeredPaneDemo by making the following changed to the `createColoredLabel(...)` method:

```
    JLabel label = null;

    if (color.equals(Color.green))
    {
        label = new JLabel(text)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean contains(int x, int y)
            {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
    else
        label = new JLabel(text);

    //JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
```

Comment: I found that editing the contains function for the layers like you mentioned at the end worked well. By making overlaying layers return false when they were not visible allowed lower layers to express their cursors, thanks!